# Need to retrieve values that falls in between two columns

Tags: sql

A table has columns Low and High. These columns contains range. Now I want to retrieve records when given value is present in between these columns:

```
Low      High
0450     0459
0760     0765
0460     0467
0360     0369
```

I want to retrieve records where `'0464'`, `'0365'`, `'0466'` is present in between low and high.

I have got to retrieve if it is one record
As

```
select * 
from tablename 
where '0465' between low and high
```

But I want the same for multiple values

Comment: What is data type of the `Low` and `High` columns?

Comment: What is your expected output from that query, and if not already correct, what are you actually getting?  Note that if you want to use the low and high columns as numbers, then you might want to consider making those columns some sort of numeric type.

Comment: You could use [`OR` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why are you using strings when it's obviously numbers you are dealing with?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

## OR operator

You could use [`OR` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) in `WHERE` clause to concatenate multiple conditions. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Ranges
WHERE (0464 BETWEEN low AND high) OR (0365 BETWEEN low AND high) OR (0466 BETWEEN low AND high);
```

Also it is possible to define custom SQL-function that will concatenate predicates via `OR` operator. The function will allow you to simplify the query syntax. To define custom function see documentation for your database management system.

## CROSS JOIN

Another way is to build all combinations of ranges and filter values. Suppose, there are two tables in your database. Table `Ranges` defines `low` and `high` boundes of ranges, and table `Filter` contains set of values that using for ranges filtering. So, the following query returns all ranges that include values from the `Filter` table:

```
SELECT low, high
FROM Ranges, Filter
WHERE Filter.val BETWEEN Ranges.low AND Ranges.high;
```

**Note**, the query result contains duplicates of ranges. If you need to get unique ranges then use `GROUP BY` clause or `DISTINCT` operator.

A temporary table, a subquery or a collection could be used instead of `Filter` table.

See also [live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d4bc/9).

Comment: Yes i can use OR but when we have some 100's of values it will be difficult

Comment: @sufalag , then you need to define custom SQL-function. If you specify your database engine, then I can provide link to details.

Comment: It is Oracle.Thankyou

Comment: @sufalag , see [User-Defined Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions231.htm) documentation.

Comment: Thankyou for the document

Comment: @sufalag, I have an idea to solve your question using cross join. The details in updated answer.

Comment: Can i add a where to this for filter.val in ('101','102','103')? Will it work the right way

Comment: @sufalag , you could try it yourself using the live example. It's runnable and editable, so it helps you to get started any experiment ;)